# Aptana3 rename variable in a file

Tags: javascript, variables, editor, aptana, rename

It is very useful for with CTRL+1 and then CTRL+2 in Eclipse for rename a variable in certain scope.

But in Aptana 3, in javascript editor, I can't find this function, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aptana does not have this feature. Check this [IDE comparative](http://www.oio.de/public/opensource/comparison-IDE-for-HTML5-CSS3-JavaScript-shootout.htm):

[image]