# aptana studio 3 refactor rename operation unavailable on javascript variable

Tags: javascript, refactoring, aptana3

I downloaded and began using Aptana Studio 3 today to work on a JS project. Having used Eclipse for years, I looked forward to using a tool with which I was familiar and provided refactorings like those with which I am familiar when editing java. Unfortunately, I tried a very simple refactor rename of a var which throws up a modal dialog error box stating:

"Select a javaScript project, source folder, resource, or a JavaScript file, or a non-readonly type, var, function, parameter, local variable or type variable."

In the following code snippet, I tried renaming the var SummaryResponse. Why does this fail?

```
  it('should return a promise that returns an error object when the request for contact changes failed', function() {
    var mockResponse = {
      message: 'Invalid Access',
      exception: 'AccessDeniedException'
    };

    var uri = '/BackOffice/v3/' + ipCookie('uriuserid') + '/contacts/changes';
    uri = encodeURIComponent(uri);

    httpBackend.whenGET(drexServiceHost + '/ExplorerService/gateway?env=DEV' + '&uri=' + uri).respond(400, mockResponse);

    var summaryResponse;

    var promise = service.getContactChanges();
    promise.then(function(result) {
      summaryResponse = result;
    });

    httpBackend.flush();

    expect(summaryResponse.status).toBeDefined();
    expect(summaryResponse.status).toEqual('error');
    expect(summaryResponse.errorMessage).toBeDefined();
  });
```

Comment: i dropped this tool and use atom instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that Aptana does not provide code refactoring features at all for JavaScript... please have a look here:
[Aptana3 rename variable in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22389718/aptana3-rename-variable-in-a-file)

For me issue was to rename variable in scope of single .js file. Well, if such task is overwhelming for tool, for me that's a sign it's time to drop tool.